# Resolving Constructor dependencies from another objects properties with Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, prism

I have a Window with a series of User Controls that can be swapped in and out. All of the User Control View Models depend on things that are stored in the Window View Model. For example, the Window has a User property that I need to provide to the User Controls View Models when they are resolved.

I found this:

```
container.Resolve<IFoo>(new ParameterOverrides<Foo> { { "name", "bar" }, { "address", 42 } });"
```

Which looks like what i need, but my View Models do not have access to the container. I thought about moving this in to a Factory, but the View Models are auto-wired with Prism.

So essentially, I would like to know how can I provide my auto-wired view models with parameters from an existing instance that the container had already instanced?  The View Models could be registered as a singleton if needed. If I do that, then in my bootstrapper, would I just resolve the parent view model during the resolving of my children view models? If so, how do I go about resolving the parent Window during the resolution of the child view model?

Comment: You say that the viewmodels can't access the container, is there any reason why not? Can you not pass the container as a parameter into the viewmodel constructor?

Comment: I was trying to keep the container at the root level and only pass in dependencies to the view model, since that's kind of the point of DI. However, even if I injected the container in to the VM, it wouldn't solve the problem. Prism auto wires the VM to the view. When a user control is instanced, I have no way to do constructor Parma injection, because the parent VM doesn't know the child VM exists, so there's no way to provide a value from parent to child.

Comment: It sounds like you might only be half using prism. I found that one has to  kind of go all the way, and then it works quite well. If you define regions within the parent view and use the prism navigation process to load your user controls into those regions, prism (and unity or whatever di) will construct the required view models for the child controls. You can then control exactly what is injected into the child controls through that process.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the project is to far along to change our navigation structure in a timely manor. I wish I had started out using Prism all the way but we didn't.